# Don´t execute my script, hide boostrap modal in blade

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I´ve the following code in a view that I want to show, but not show the script, and don´t work

I can´t hide my modal when I load the view

```
 @if(!empty($status) && $status == 'ok_create')
    <script>
    alert('hi');
    $("#box-modal").modal('hide');
    </script>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> El usuario fue creado con exito 
    </div>

    @endif
```

[image]

My repository github => https://github.com/Mangulomx/viversoft1

Comment: does the alert show up ? and do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: I don´t see any error in console

Comment: oh yeah its `$('#box-modal').modal('hide');` its not `.show('hide')`

Comment: I write wrong. but don´t work. I modified it

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is not in modal but in place where you write the script. How do you get this `$status`? If it is answer on ajax query or something that you get after page loaded, it will not work in php code, you should place it all include the condition in javascript.